# Public Sub New() firing function in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hey all I am converting some C# code to VB.net and noticed that the C# code has a **Public Sub New()**. The C# code is this:

```
private readonly SController _controller; 

public SView():this(new SController()) { }

public SView(SController controller)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _controller = controller;
    controller.EnumerateDevices(deviceDropdown.Items);
    _thread = new Thread(ReadLoop) {IsBackground = true};
    _thread.Start();
}
```

And converting the above to VB.net:

```
Private ReadOnly _controller As SController

Public Sub New()
   Me.New(New SController())
End Sub

Public Sub New(controller As SController)
   InitializeComponent()
   _controller = controller
   controller.EnumerateDevices(deviceDropdown.Items)
   _thread = New Thread(AddressOf ReadLoop) With { _
      .IsBackground = True _
   }

   _thread.Start()
End Sub
```

The problem I am running into is that since VB starts with:

```
Private Sub SView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

How can I tell it to fire off the **Public Sub New()** function?

I tried just putting:

```
Private Sub SView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.New(New SController())
End Sub
```

But it gives me the error of:

```
Constructor call is valid only as the first statement in an instance constructor.
```

Any help would be great to solve this issue!

**update**

```
Private Sub SView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   Dim _sView As New SView
End Sub
```

It never hits the Load when I put a break on line **Dim _sView As New SView**

Comment: `Sub New` is the constructor and it will fire at the same time it would in C# - when you create the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to call the logic in the constructor *on an already-constructed instance*, you need to refactor to move that logic out of the constructoir:

```
Private ReadOnly _controller As SController

Public Sub New()
   Me.New(New SController())
End Sub

Public Sub New(controller As SController)
   Initialize(controller)
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize(controller As SController)
   InitializeComponent()
   _controller = controller
   controller.EnumerateDevices(deviceDropdown.Items)
   _thread = New Thread(AddressOf ReadLoop) With { _
      .IsBackground = True _
   }

   _thread.Start()
End Sub
```

Then instead of calling `Me.New(New SController())` you'll call `Me.Initialize(New SController())`

Comment: **Me.Initialize(New SController())** does not work. Error of **Error 'Initialize' is not a member of 'S.View.SView'.**

Comment: Are you calling it from within the view?  I made it private so it couldn't be called from outside the view, but you can make it public if you need to.

Comment: **_controller/_thread** are *read only* and that's where the error is now.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell it to fire off the Public Sub New() function?

You can't. `Sub New()` is the constructor of your class, which is executed to initialize an instance of the class. You can't call it after the object has been created.

Comment: Then how would I go about firing off the **Public Sub New()** function so that the **New(controller As ScaleController)** fires as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your default constructor (the one without any parameters) is called when the form is instantiated and prior to the Load event firing. If you want to verify this, place a breakpoint within the constructor and debug your solution.

Comment: Then how would I go about firing off the **Public Sub New()** function so that the **New(controller As ScaleController)** fires as well?

Comment: Whenever a new Form1 is created like so: Dim Form1() as new Form1(), the default constructor is called. In this case, the default constructor calls the parameterized constructor, passing in a new SController.

Comment: I feel like you may need to brush up on your knowledge of construction in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z08e49e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`Sub New` is called when you create a New instance.
"Sub **New**" ===> "Dim foo As **New** FooBar" Get it?

Some confusion may be because your SView constructor is overloaded:

```
' simple constructor
Public Sub New()
   Me.New(New SController())       ' calls overload below
End Sub

Public Sub New(controller As SController)

   InitializeComponent()           ' this is apparently a form????

   _controller = controller
   controller.EnumerateDevices(deviceDropdown.Items)
   _thread = New Thread(AddressOf ReadLoop) With { _
      .IsBackground = True }

   _thread.Start()
End Sub
```

It can be called with or without a reference to a controller:

```
Dim _sView As New SView
' or
Dim _ctrlr As New SController
Dim _sView As New SView(_ctrlr)
```

In the first case, your SView will create its own new controller.  In the second,  it will use the one passed to it in the constructor call (`New SView(_ctrlr)`).  In **both** cases your new object **will** have a controller object.

In cases where a new class object should not exist without the ctor arg, just remove the simple (empty) constructor so an exception is thrown:

```
Dim emp As New Employee(empName)
' this one fails if you remove the "Sub New()":
Dim emp As New Employee()
```

If you only ever want to create new instances with the controller you created, just remove the simple/empty constructor.

**EDIT**

`It never hits the Load when I put a break on line [Dim _sView As New SView]`

Loading a form is not the same as creating a form instance.  Forms are just classes and the Load event is called **the first time** you use invoke the `Show` method on the **object**. This is a **good** thing as it allows us to create a form instance and work with it **before** it is shown. Longer notation:

```
Dim _sView As SView          ' simple DECLARES the object name and type
_sView = New SView           ' create instance (exec [Sub new])
_sView.FormSetup             ' do some first time only stuff
_sView.Show                  ' show the form (fires [Load] event)
```

`FormSetup` might be a method I write which is some tasks to be done only the first time it is used.  If I subsequently just `Hide` the form, I can skip all that rather than have it in a `Load` event.  The comments however explain whats going on for each line.

Comment: see Edit - creating a new instance doesnt result in a form Load - that happens only when you SHOW it.